# Improving/ Optimizing Performance Query in MySQL PHP

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, php, query-performance

I have a invoices, invoices_items, order, order_items. Invoices and Orders tables contains around 1 Millions records. Invoices_items and Orders_items tables contains more than 2 Millions records. Items table contains 2 Hundred Thousands records. Now I want to generate a report based on my filter like customers, item categories and more.... Please refer queries.

Running on PHP 5.6. MySql 5.7 and Apache2.

```
SELECT
  `si_items`.`item_id`
  , SUM(qty) AS `qty`
  , IFNULL(SUM(selling_price * (qty)), 0) AS `salestotal`
  , GROUP_CONCAT(si.id) AS `siso_id` 
  , MAX(si.date_transaction) AS `date_transaction`
FROM
  `invoice_items` AS `si_items`
  LEFT JOIN `invoice` AS `si`
    ON si.id = si_items.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN `items`
    ON si_items.item_id = items.id
WHERE (
    DATE_FORMAT(si.date_transaction, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2019-01-01'
    AND '2019-02-15'
  )
  AND (si.approved = 1)
  AND (si.deleted = 0)
  AND (items.deleted = 0)
    GROUP BY `item_id`

     UNION

SELECT
  `so_items`.`item_id`
  , SUM(qty) AS `qty`
  , IFNULL(SUM(selling_price * (qty)), 0) AS `salestotal`
  , GROUP_CONCAT(so.id) AS `soso_id` 
  , MAX(so.date_transaction) AS `date_transaction`
FROM
  `order_items` AS `so_items`
  LEFT JOIN `order` AS `so`
    ON so.id = so_items.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN `items`
    ON so_items.item_id = items.id
WHERE (
    DATE_FORMAT(so.date_transaction, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2019-01-01'
    AND '2019-02-15'
  )
  AND (so.approved = 1)
  AND (so.deleted = 0)
  AND (items.deleted = 0)
    GROUP BY `item_id`
```

When I executed this query for 50 days. It took *1 minute 20 seconds* to execute this query.

INDEXES are added in tables

Invoice & Order Tables

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
KEY `approved` (`approved`),
KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
KEY `finalised` (`finalised`),
KEY `rp_status` (`rp_status`),
KEY `sales_types_id` (`sales_types_id`),
KEY `account_type_id` (`account_type_id`),
KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
KEY `date_transaction` (`date_transaction`)
```

Invoices_items & Order_items

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
KEY `vat_id` (`vat_id`),
KEY `qty` (`qty`),
```

Explain Query

[image]

I need to increase performance of this query. Could you please guide me how to proceed?

**Show Create Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_types_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `quote_validity` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `delivery_method_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `sales_representative_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `account_type_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vat_exempted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `description` text,
  `finalised` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Not Yet finalised - status=1; Need Approval - status = 2; Approved - status = 3',
  `approved` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `approved_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `default_sales_location_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0-Yes; 1-No',
  `generate_do` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `generate_dn` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `do_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `cn_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `rp_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `dm_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `currency_id` char(36),
  `exchange_rate_id` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `exchange_rate` double DEFAULT '1',
  `date_transaction` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `modified_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
  KEY `approved` (`approved`),
  KEY `branch_id` (`branch_id`),
  KEY `cn_status` (`cn_status`),
  KEY `created_user_id` (`created_user_id`),
  KEY `date_created` (`date_created`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `do_status` (`do_status`),
  KEY `finalised` (`finalised`),
  KEY `reference` (`reference`),
  KEY `rp_status` (`rp_status`),
  KEY `sales_types_id` (`sales_types_id`),
  KEY `account_type_id` (`account_type_id`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `date_transaction` (`date_transaction`),
  KEY `default_sales_location_id` (`default_sales_location_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `invoice_items` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` double DEFAULT '0',
  `cost_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `list_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `selling_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `unit_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `vat` double DEFAULT '0',
  `amount` double DEFAULT '0',
  `special_discount` double DEFAULT '0',
  `price_change_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `remarks` text,
  `vat_id` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `stock_category_id` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1: Stockable 2: Service',
  `is_giftitem` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1: Gift Item 0: NO Gift',
  `item_type_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `modified_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `stock_category_id` (`stock_category_id`),
  KEY `item_type_status` (`item_type_status`),
  KEY `vat_id` (`vat_id`),
  KEY `amount` (`amount`),
  KEY `qty` (`qty`),
  KEY `unit_price` (`unit_price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: All your LEFT JOINs are INNER JOINs. Replace.

Comment: What is datatype of invoice.date_transaction and order.date_transaction?

Comment: *INDEXES are added in tables* In most cases (including this) one query can use only one index per each table copy. So some indices are excess I think...

Comment: @Akina, I will update Inner Join. Date transaction date type is datetime.

Comment: *Date transaction date type is datetime.* Alter `DATE_FORMAT(si.date_transaction, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-15'` to `si.date_transaction BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-02-15 23:59:59'`. Never use functions with fields as arguments if possible.

Comment: Create indices: `invoice_items (item_id, parent_id)` and the same for `order_items`, `invoice (deleted, approved, date_transaction, id)` and the same for `order`, and `items (deleted, id)`. And remove unnesessary indices (all indices for which you cannot say exactly where they are needed).

Comment: @Akina. thanks. i will try to change as you have mentioned indexes.